# EF6: Adding an entity with many-to-many and the main entity's children with many-to-many

Tags: entity-framework-6

Basically I'm trying to add a new entity (Person) with its children (Addresses); and both of these entities do have many to many relationships. I'm using Entity Framework 6.1.3.

> Attaching an entity of type 'Feature' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

But I'm getting the following error even though I think that I'm using the proper Attach method to indicate that both Hobbies and Features already exist in the database.

It seems like if I try to attach only one featureSet instead of 2, then it works fine. But the problem seems to be when the same Feature is selected for 2 addresses. I've even tried to attach only the distinct feature, but then a different error comes. Then the code tries to ADD a NEW feature which I don't want.

Here is my code that I'm working with:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Personname { get; set }
    public ICollection<Hobby> Hobbies { get; set; } // Many to Many with Hobbies
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; } // One to Many (many side)
}


// Many to Many: Represented in database as PersonHobby (eg. Reading, Writing; User could select multiple hobbies of a person)
public class Hobby
{
    public int HobbyId { get; set; }
    public string Hobbyname { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Person> People { get; set; } // Many-To-Many with Person
}


public class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }

    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Feature> Features { get; set; } 
}


// Many to Many: Represented in database as AddressFeature (e.g Air Conditioning, Central Heating; User could select multiple features of a single address)
public class Feature
{
    public int FeatureId { get; set; }
    public string Featurename { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; } // Many-To-Many with Addresses
}
```

Now, I want to add a NEW person with multiple addresses in the same shot.

```cs
public static Person GetFakePerson()
{
        Person person = new Person();

    person.PersonName = "Peter";
        person.PersonEmail = "demo@demo.com";

    person.Hobbies = new List<Hobby>();
        person.Hobbies.Add(new Hobby { HobbyId = 1 });
        person.Hobbies.Add(new Hobby { HobbyId = 2 });

    person.Addresses = new List<Address>();

    // In real world, the user in GUI will be selecting the following features as the checkboxes within the Address object.
    List<Feature> featureSet_1 = new List<Feature>();
        featureSet_1.Add(new Feature { FeatureId = 1 });
        featureSet_1.Add(new Feature { FeatureId = 2 });
        person.Addresses.Add(new Address { Line1 = "123 St", City = "Fishers", State = "IN", Features = featureSet_1 });

    List<Feature> featureSet_2 = new List<Feature>();
        featureSet_2.Add(new Feature { FeatureId = 1 });
        featureSet_2.Add(new Feature { FeatureId = 2 });
        person.Addresses.Add(new Address { Line1 = "987 Avenue", City = "Carmel", State = "IN", Features = featureSet_2 });

    return person;
}

// PersonService has this method
public int AddPerson(Person person)
{
    try
    {
        using (MyDbContext dbContext = new MyDbContext())
        {
            person.Addresses.ToList().ForEach(y => y.Features.ToList().ForEach(x => dbContext.Features.Attach(x)));

            person.Hobbies.ToList().ForEach(x => dbContext.Hobbies.Attach(x)); // This seems to be working

            dbContext.People.Add(person);

            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            return person.PersonId;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception exp)
    {
        // Catch exception here
    }
}
```

This is how I'm calling the above mentioned function:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PersonService _personService = new PersonService(); // This class holds the AddPerson()
        Person samplePerson = GetFakePerson();

    int peronId = _personService.AddPerson(samplePerson);
}
```

Comment: I've even tried to attach only the distinct feature, but then a differnet error comes. Then the code tries to ADD a NEW feature which I don't want. Basically, the new instances are being sent by the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing *nearly* everything right. The only mistake you make is in

```cs
List<Feature> featureSet_1 = new List<Feature>();
    featureSet_1.Add(new Feature { FeatureId = 1 });
    featureSet_1.Add(new Feature { FeatureId = 2 });
...

List<Feature> featureSet_2 = new List<Feature>();
    featureSet_2.Add(new Feature { FeatureId = 1 });
    featureSet_2.Add(new Feature { FeatureId = 2 });
...
```

`featureSet_1` and `featureSet_2` are two lists, together containing *four* `Feature` instances. All EF knows, is that these four instances are attached to the context. At the third instance, the first in `featureSet_2`, it complains that this primary key value is already "taken".

You have to assign the same two `Feature` instances to both `Address`es:

```cs
var f1 = new Feature { FeatureId = 1 };
var f2 = new Feature { FeatureId = 2 };
List<Feature> featureSet_1 = new List<Feature> { f1, f2 };
...

List<Feature> featureSet_2 = new List<Feature>  { f1, f2 };
...
```

(Maybe EF is even happy if you assign `featureSet_1` twice, to both addresses).

Comment: List<Feature> distinctFeaturesThatNeedToBeAttached = new List<Feature>();
person.Addresses.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Features.ToList().ForEach(y => distinctFeaturesThatNeedToBeAttached.Add(y)));
distinctFeaturesThatNeedToBeAttached = distinctFeaturesThatNeedToBeAttached.DistinctBy(x => x.FeatureId).ToList();

distinctFeaturesThatNeedToBeAttached.ToList<Feature>().ForEach(x => dbContext.Features.Attach(x));

Comment: I've used the immediately above technique to attach only the 2 (distinct) features. But then I'm getting the different error as follows:

Comment: The code in your comment only attaches features to the first address. Those for the second address are filtered out by `DistinctBy`. So EF will see them as new, and insert them.

Comment: Then I got this error: "The FeatureName field is required."; and entity state is Added. It seems like EF is trying to insert a new feature instead of attaching the existing one.

Comment: The validation error is because you work with so-called *stub entities*. That's a valid technique, but often it requires you to disable validation on Save.

Comment: in that case, how could I tell EF to attach instead of insert?

Comment: `dbContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;`

Comment: I tried that (ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false) but then I got the error saying "Cannot insert FeatureName = null) because EF is trying to insert the new Feature instead of attaching.

Comment: List<Feature> distinctFeaturesThatNeedToBeAttached = new List<Feature>();
person.Addresses.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Features.ToList().ForEach(y => distinctFeaturesThatNeedToBeAttached.Add(y)));
distinctFeaturesThatNeedToBeAttached = distinctFeaturesThatNeedToBeAttached.DistinctBy(x => x.FeatureId).ToList();
distinctFeaturesThatNeedToBeAttached.ToList<Feature>().ForEa‌​ch(x => dbContext.Features.Attach(x));
person.Hobbies.ToList().ForEach(x => dbContext.Hobbies.Attach(x));
dbContext.People.Add(person);
dbContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
dbContext.SaveChanges();

Comment: I've use a new instance for Feature as it is coming from UI. I've updated the original question with the UI code. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Then you have to write code that replaces the pseudo-equal features by the ones in the other address. No other option. You simply can't attach different instances with identical PK values.

Comment: Thanks Gert for your help. I'm accepting your answer. If possible give me a pointer for "Then you have to write code that replaces the pseudo-equal features by the ones in the other address"

Comment: Something like `foreach(Feature feature in selectedFeatureIds.Select(id => new Feature { FeatureId = id }))` and add the instances to addresses instead of new instances for each address.

Comment: great. Thanks a lot. God bless you.